# I have an ipad mock up however the screen is being bleached out, is there any way i can have the screen ignore the lighting i have on the file?

Tags: modeling, lighting

I have an iPad mockup however the screen is being bleached out, is there any way I can have the screen ignore the lighting I have on the file?

Ive set the lighting up correct for the rest of the mock up its literally just the screen is this a node fix?[image][image][image]
Cheers
CalPol

Answer (score 1):

You may try to plug the image output into the emission input of the *Principled* node. This will make the material emit light.

Comment: Amazing thank you, its way closer now, but is there a way of brightening it a bit, the top band of the website is meant to be white :S would adding the brightness contrast node between the img imput and principled node work?

Comment: You can also try plugging the image into the emission input and the base color, which will preserve more of the original colors. Then you can use the emission strength as brightness control.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I am not sure what the end result should be, but if you are looking for something like this:

[image]

you can use these nodes:

[image]

and put down exposure to this:

[image]

or if you want more light from the ipad like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

or...if you just delete all your lights and only let your iPad light your scene with the emitter shader...and cycles...it looks like this:

[image]

***************** OLD ANSWER ***************

Instead of plugging it in the shader you can plug the image directly to your material output.

Here you can see the comparison:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) ive tried that one but it comes out dark would it be the global settings being a issue?

Comment: i don't know your setup....so it's hard to tell. If you could provide blend file...i can tell ;)

Comment: oh lordy my bad, sorry im kinda new to this, heres a wetransfer link to download the blender file :) - https://we.tl/t-F2jMbcJem5

Comment: thank you, could you please do file -> external data -> pack resources and then save and upload again, so we see your assets too? thank you!

Comment: done :) https://we.tl/t-f8mBKmrwus

Comment: Way closer than i was before for sure thank you :)

Comment: i was aiming for this hopefully - https://we.tl/t-iNC8jOqkm6 but with a white background

Comment: pure white? than you could go with compositing....

Comment: ah okay, i haven't reached that part of blender yet, with the compositing section still allow for the iPad to have shadows on the background?
also, do you know any good tuts on the compositing section?

Comment: you can just search in google....and for beginners...i think that's ok: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEpVyEi1Hts

Comment: Amazing thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome